# How to set path resource from EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-videoview

I want to play a video from my raw folder by typing the filename in a `EditText`.
The following (static) code works. But how can I replace the `R.raw`-name by the input from the `EditText`?

```
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.howtogetthisfromedittext;
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
videoView.start();
```

Comment: why don't you add more details? What is the problem you are facing? What is your expectation by posting it here?

Comment: I want to play a video from my R.raw folder, I have 2 videos, "test1" and test2" . Now if i enter "test1" in editText and hit the play button, the video will be played.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the identifier of the resource for that to work, which can be retrieved by its name using:

```
int id = getResources().
    getIdentifier("name_of_resource", "id", getPackageName());
```

So your new code would become:

```
int videoResource = getResources().
    getIdentifier("video1", "raw", getPackageName());
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + videoResource;
```

Edited : 
You can get `Edittext`  String value simply using this line code :

```
   String video_name= edittext.gettext().tostring();
```

Answer (score 1):

To play a video from Raw Folder

```
VideoView view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_file;
view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
view.start();
```

Create `videoView` in your xml file. The name of your video is placed in place of `video_file`.

Comment: That's really working, but my question is: can I replace the R.video_file getting from edittext

Answer (score 1):

To put all the pieces from the previous answered question together.

To get the text from the `EditText` use that code:

```
final String videoName = editText.getText().toString();
```

After that you can use that `videoName` as filename from the `raw` folder like the following:

```
final int videoResource = getResources().getIdentifier(videoName, "raw", getPackageName());
final String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + videoResource
```

Then you can put the `path` to your `VideoView`:

```
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
```

Now you can write `test1` in your `EditText` and the video `R.raw.test1` will be used.

Answer (score 1):

String word = et1.getText().toString();

```
    int videoResource = getResources().
            getIdentifier(word, "raw", getPackageName());
    String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + videoResource;
    videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    videoview.start();
```